# NullPointerException error in Main

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Trying to read a file when the user enters the file name into the console. The program compiles and runs with no errors. Once you enter the file name and press enter, you get this error. Can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Writer.<init>(Writer.java:88)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:113)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:100)
at propertylistings.propertylistings.main(propertylistings.java:34)

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class propertylistings {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    throws FileNotFoundException

    {

        // Prompt for the input file name

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input file: ");
        String inputFileName = console.next();
        BufferedWriter pwfo = null;

        try {
            pwfo = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\agentReport.txt",
                    true));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
//next line is LINE 34 
        PrintWriter pwo = new PrintWriter(pwfo);

        // Construct property type treeSet

        Set<String> propertyTypes = pTypes(inputFileName);

        // Print property types from treeSet

        for (String type : propertyTypes) {
            System.out.println(type);
            pwo.println(type);
        }

        // Construct agent ids and values treeSet

        Set<String> agentRpt = agentValue(inputFileName);

        // Print agent Ids and values from key set

        for (String tail : agentRpt) {
            {
                System.out.println(tail);
                pwo.println(tail);
            }
        }
        pwo.flush();
        pwo.close();
    }

    // Reads the input file.
    // @return the alphabetized property types in uppercase.

    public static Set<String> pTypes(String inputFileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException

    // Construct a tree set to return property types
    {
        Set<String> type = new TreeSet<String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));

        // Use delimiters to select specific chars for set

        in.useDelimiter("[1234567890. ]");
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            type.add(in.next().toUpperCase());
        }
        in.close();
        return type;
    }

    // Reads the input file.
    // @returns the Agent id's and corresponding property values.

    public static Set<String> agentValue(String inputFileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        TreeSet<String> tail = new TreeSet<String>();
        SortedMap<String, Number> agentValues = new TreeMap<String, Number>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
        String line = inputFileName;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            try {
                line = in.nextLine();
                String[] fields = line.split("[\\s}]");
                String agentId = (fields[3]);
                Double pValue = Double.parseDouble(fields[2]);

                if (agentValues.containsKey(agentId)) {
                    pValue += agentValues.get(agentId).doubleValue();
                }
                agentValues.put(agentId, pValue);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            // Create keyMap with all keys and values

            Set<String> keySet = agentValues.keySet();
            for (String key : keySet) {
                Number value = agentValues.get(key);

                // System.out.println(key + ":" + value);

                tail.add(key + ":" + value);
            }
        }
        return tail;
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (IOException e) { }` isn't good.  Most likely you've received an `IOException` and ignored it, leaving `pwfo` `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a stacktrace in your catch block and you'll know the exact error.

```
   try {
         pwfo = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\agentReport.txt", true));
         } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printstacktrace();
       }
```

Comment: Adding the stacktrace worked. It was trying to write the file to a folder that needed admin rights. Thanks you the help!!